# Long Term effects of saturating isolation txfr

Tags: transformer, magnetics

I have a 1:1 isolation transformer that's rated for 25VA. I'm consuming 30VA, 20W.

I've noticed because I'm saturating it, the txfr is no longer 1:1, it's more like 1:1.1.

Other than this issue, for my application is working fine.

Is there anything else I should be worried about? Will saturating the transformer this way "wear" or damage the txfr out over time?

Edit:

Bottom meter is primary (main supply)

Top meter is secondary (powering my load)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When the transformers primary is connected to source (mains power supply), then the flux in the transformer is nominal, even if the secondary is left open. The xfrmr can't be saturated by means of overloading it, therefore your theory doesn't stand. If the transormer is overloaded 15VA instead of 10VA, then it will overheat and the coils will melt down.

Comment: Lemme attach a snap

Comment: Overheating is due to I squared R losses due to overloading, not saturation. When saturation occurs, it is due to over voltage on the primary, or proper voltage but frequency less than rated.